# Laravel 5 adding HTML to email

Tags: php, html, email, laravel, newline

I'm currently trying to create a HTML email in Laravel 5 and I have some text (which contains `<br/>` elements) I want to insert in the email. I use the following piece of code to send the email:

```
Mail::send(array('html' => 'emails.newinvoice'), array('text' => $emailtext), function($message) use ($email, $subject, $contact_company)
{
    $message->to($email, $contact_company)->subject($subject);
});
```

So the `$emailtext` variable contains some text with HTML tags. In my `emails.newinvoice` layout view, I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>{{{ $text }}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When sending the email, the inserted text in my mail and the HTML elements in that text are displayed as normal characters which means that my email shows up like:

```
test<br/>test
```

Instead of

```
test
test
```

How can I make sure that the HTML tags in the inserted text get rendered as HTML and not as plain text?

Comment: What happens when you use {!! $text !!}?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to specify `html` key in the first parameter:

```
Mail::send( ['html' => 'emails.newinvoice'], ['text' => $emailtext], 
//           ^^^^
```

Also replace auto-escaped block `{{ }}` with unescaped `{!! !!}` in the template:

```
<p> {!! $text !!} </p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my inserted HTML still gets rendered as plain text after this change.

Comment: Thanks 

Also replace auto-escaped block {{ }} with unescaped {!! !!} in the template:

this helps me

Comment: The {!! did the trick

Answer (score 19):

You need to use:

```
{!! $text !!}
```

instead of

```
{{ $text }}
```

Blade automatically escapes any html when echoing unless you explicitly tell it not to.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah the solution above work just fine..

use `{!! $contents !!}`

instead of this

```
{{ $contents }}
```

This `{!! $contents !!}` is for allowing html
While this `{{ $contents }}` is just for plain text.

Answer (score 1):

After checking various solutions, following codes worked for me -

```
 try {
      $template_data = ['otp' => $otp, 'name' => $name];
      //send verification code
      Mail::send(['html' => 'email.account_verification'], $template_data,
                function ($message) use ($email) {
                   $message->to($email)
                   ->from('test@yourdamin.com') //not sure why I have to add this
                   ->subject('Account verification');
      });

      return Response::json(['code' => 200, 'msg' => 'Sent successfully']);

      } catch (Exception $ex) {
            return Response::json(['code' => 200, 'msg' => 'Something went wrong, please try later.']);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ShouldQueue to send email, you should run the command 'php artisan queue:work' again, then you run your app again. After that, you check the receiver email, you can see the email content displayed in html format.