# Laravel 5.2 sending email as plain text, not html

Tags: laravel-5

Recently, I have upgraded my project from `Laravel 5.1` to `Laravel 5.2` and I am facing a strange issue.

The emails I was sending in HTML format are not getting sent as plain text with html tags inside.

The email body and subject are configurable so I read them from database, replace the variable values and set them as a body and subject.

With `Laravel 5.1` there was no issue with it. The code I am using to send email is as below:

```
Mail::send('layouts.email', $emailData, function($message) use ($emailData, $email_subject){
    $message->to($emailData['to'], $emailData['name'])->subject($email_subject);
});
```

I also have tried,

```
Mail::send(['html' => 'layouts.email'], $emailData, function($message) use ($emailData, $email_subject){
    $message->to($emailData['to'], $emailData['name'])->subject($email_subject);
});
```

The `layout.email.blade.php` template is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>

    <body>
    {{$message_body}}

    </body>
</html>
```

But the problem is still there. Can anybody guide me please?

Comment: I got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891315/laravel-5-adding-html-to-email