# Html tags are sent when i am sending mail in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the tiny editor and i want to send an email with formatting without HTML tags but it sends HTML tags. I am using laravel. I am giving below how my mail comes. and what I have to do to send mail to multiple recipients. Please help me to make it run successfully.
Controller:-

```
\Mail::send('emails.contact',
array(                 
'email' => $request->get('email'),                 
'sub' => $request->get('sub'),
'bodyMessage' => $request->get('message'),
), function($message) use ($request)
{
$message->from('harsha1604gandhi@gmail.com');
$message->to($request->get('email'));
$message->subject($request->sub);
});
```

**View:-**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="contact" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">To:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" multiple>
<a id="bccemail" style="float: right;padding-left:5px;">Bcc</a>
<a id="ccemail" style="float: right;">Cc</a>        
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="divcc" style="display: none;">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailcc" placeholder="Cc" name="emailcc">       
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="divbcc" style="display: none;">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailbcc" placeholder="Bcc" name="emailbcc">       
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Subject:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">          
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sub" placeholder="Enter Subject" name="sub">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">        
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<div class="">
<textarea name="message" id="msg"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">        
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<script>                    
tinymce.init({
selector: '#msg',
plugins: 'code link image media paste anchor quickbars'
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ccemail").click(function(){
$("#divcc").toggle();
});
$("#bccemail").click(function(){
$("#divbcc").toggle();
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Mail:-
[Here my screenshot of mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ee5b.png)

Comment: Where's the email template? You are probably using escape blade tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 adding HTML to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891315/laravel-5-adding-html-to-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your email template view, but I imagine that you are using blade `{{ }}` statement to output the message to it.

But, accordingly to Laravel Docs:

> Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks.

and

> If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> .    Hello, {!! $name !!}.

So you must replace the `{{ }}` by `{!! !}}` where you output the message containing html code.